# How to download with python to firebase storage image?

Tags: image, python-2.7, firebase-storage

I could upload image to firebase storage with python. but I couldn't find how to download image with python to firebase storage.

Answer (score 0):

This is similar question to [How do I get url with token of uploaded file to firebase storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72037182/how-do-i-get-url-with-token-of-uploaded-file-to-firebase-storage/73398502#73398502)

#### Change the security rule to that specific folder

- Make sure you upload publically visible images to that specific folder
- It doesn't require any access token to access such images
- Capturing media token can only be done by the `Client SDK` and not available in the `Admin SDK` for `firebase-admin` python

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
     // Explicitly define rules for the 'path/to/myfile/' pattern
    match /path/to/myfile/{allPaths}{
      allow  write: if request.auth != null; // Only Auth person can read
      allow  read: if request.auth == null; // Anyone can read
    }
    // This will be defined for everything else
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow  write: if request.auth != null; // Only auth person can write
      allow  read: if request.auth != null; // Only auth person can read
    }
  }
}
```

#### Sample python code

```py
storageBucket='myapp.appspot.com'
bucket_path="path/to/myfile/temp.mp3"
firebase_storageURL = 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/{}/o/{}?alt=media'.format(storageBucket, bucket_path)
```