# How do I get url with token of uploaded file to firebase storage?

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage, firebase-admin

I am trying to get the URL of a file I'm uploading to Firebase Storage. I want the URL that includes the token at the end, the one that looks like this:
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/myapp.appspot.com/o/folder%myfile?alt=media&token=mytoken

So far this is my code:

```
from firebase_admin import credentials, initialize_app

cred = credentials.Certificate("serviceAccountKey.json")
initialize_app(cred, {'storageBucket': 'myapp.appspot.com'})

bucket = storage.bucket()
path = "path/to/myfile"
blob = self.bucket.blob(path)
blob.upload_from_filename("temp.mp3")

# I only know how to get this URL but it's not the one that I want
blob.make_public()
url = blob.public_url
```

I also don't want the signed URL that expires.

I've seen people mention the function `getDownloadURL` but I don't know how I can use it with firebase-admin in Python.

I've checked https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/blobs.html but all I could find about URLs was either signedURL or publicURL

Comment: Hi @APL2020 , currently, there's no way you can get the download url with an access token incorporated on it using Python. One way is to upload your file with a custom access token and use your custom access token to create the download URL.  Firebase Admin SDK just wraps the Cloud Storage SDK. It eventually exposes all the same objects and APIs. What's your use-case on which you want to have the Firebase Storage URL with access token in it?

Comment: Hello @MarcAnthonyB, thanks for your reply. I was afraid that was the case, but I can do what you suggest no problem. I'm new to all of this and I was just worried about possible security issues regarding the no-token URL

Comment: How are you going to use the file that you'll get from Firebase Storage? Based on your code above, the file will be available to the public, so anyone can get/take the file if you make it public? Do you intend to make it available to the public?

Comment: Yes, this is for a music sharing platform and the files saved in the storage would be songs (and eventually images for album covers / users' profiles), so in the most basic approach, users should have access to any file

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72597432/16635269) is the link to answer provided by @MarcAnthonyB

Answer (score 0):

#### Change the security rule to that specific folder

- Make sure you upload publically visible images to that specific folder
- It doesn't require any access token to access such images
- Capturing media token can only be done by the `Client SDK` and not available in the `Admin SDK` for `firebase-admin` python

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
     // Explicitly define rules for the 'path/to/myfile/' pattern
    match /path/to/myfile/{allPaths}{
      allow  write: if request.auth != null; // Only Auth person can read
      allow  read: if request.auth == null; // Anyone can read
    }
    // This will be defined for everything else
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow  write: if request.auth != null; // Only auth person can write
      allow  read: if request.auth != null; // Only auth person can read
    }
  }
}
```

#### Sample python code

```py
storageBucket='myapp.appspot.com'
bucket_path="path/to/myfile/temp.mp3"
firebase_storageURL = 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/{}/o/{}?alt=media'.format(storageBucket, bucket_path)
```