# How to create Google Cloud storage access token programmatically python

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I need to have a public URL for a file that I am creating inside a google function.
I want therefore to create an access token :
[image]

I am able to upload the file from a python google function with the function       `blob.upload_from_string(blob_text)`, but I do not know how I can create a public url (or create an access token) for it.

Could you help me with it ?

EDITING WITH THE ANSWER (almost copy paste from [Marc Anthony B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16895640/marc-anthony-b) answer )

```
blob = bucket.blob(storage_path)
token = uuid4()
metadata = {"firebaseStorageDownloadTokens": token}
blob.metadata = metadata
download_url = 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/{}/o/{}?alt=media&token={}' \
    .format(bucket.name, storage_path.replace("/", "%2F"), token)
with open(video_file_path, 'rb') as f:
    blob.upload_from_file(f)
```

Comment: If the bucket publicly accessible? Or do you want to create a temporary downloadable URL to get the file (without any authentication to provide, the URL is enough to be authenticated)

Comment: No the bucket is not publicly accessible, but I want to create an url where without auth anybody can access the file (if possible permanently, but at least temporary). I also tried to use blob generate_signed_url, but I did not manage to have it work.
For instance [this](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/startup-backend-3036c.appspot.com/o/computedVideos%2Ftest-blob?) is the url I get for my test file.

Comment: Sorry I missed my copy paste : https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/startup-backend-3036c.appspot.com/o/computedVideos%2Ftest-blob?alt=media&token=d28f9534-ed2d-443a-bb4d-609a87932548

Comment: Hi @HeiliStanislas , have you checked my posted answer? Let me know if you have any questions or clarifications.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay, this is a side project for me ! Thank you very much for your answer, I will check it tonight, or tomorrow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firebase Storage for Python still doesn't have its own SDK but you can use `firebase-admin` instead. Firebase Admin SDKs depend on the [**Google Cloud Storage client libraries**](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries) to provide Cloud Storage access. The bucket references returned by the Admin SDK are objects defined in these libraries.

When uploading an object to Firebase Storage, you must incorporate a custom access token. You may use `UUID4` for this case. See code below:

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import storage
from uuid import uuid4

projectId = '<PROJECT-ID>'
storageBucket = '<BUCKET-NAME>'

cred = credentials.ApplicationDefault()
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {
  'projectId': projectId,
  'storageBucket': storageBucket
})

bucket = storage.bucket()

# E.g: "upload/file.txt"
bucket_path = "<BUCKET-PATH>"
blob = bucket.blob(bucket_path)

# Create a token from UUID.
# Technically, you can use any string to your token.
# You can assign whatever you want.
token = uuid4()
metadata = {"firebaseStorageDownloadTokens": token}

# Assign the token as metadata
blob.metadata = metadata

blob.upload_from_filename(filename="<FILEPATH>")

# Make the file public (OPTIONAL). To be used for Cloud Storage URL. 
blob.make_public()

# Fetches a public URL from GCS.
gcs_storageURL = blob.public_url

# Generates a URL with Access Token from Firebase.
firebase_storageURL = 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/{}/o/{}?alt=media&token={}'.format(storageBucket, bucket_path, token)

print({
  "gcs_storageURL": gcs_storageURL,
  "firebase_storageURL": firebase_storageURL
})
```

As you can see from the code above, I've mentioned GCS and Firebase URLs. If you want a public URL from GCS then you should make the object public by using the `make_public()` method. If you want to use the access token generated, then just concatenate the default Firebase URL with the variables required.

---

If the objects are already in the Firebase Storage and already have access tokens incorporated on it, then you can get it by getting the objects metadata. See code below:

```
# E.g: "upload/file.txt"
bucket_path = "<BUCKET-PATH>"
blob = bucket.get_blob(bucket_path)

# Fetches object metadata
metadata = blob.metadata

# Firebase Access Token
token = metadata['firebaseStorageDownloadTokens']

firebase_storageURL = 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/{}/o/{}?alt=media&token={}'.format(storageBucket, bucket_path, token)

print(firebase_storageURL)
```

---

For more information, you may check out this documentation:

- [Google Cloud Storage Library for Python](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/blobs.html)
- [Introduction to the Admin Cloud Storage API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/admin/start#python)

Comment: This answer is exceptional and worked perfectly for me. My one clarifying point would be that you must use `firebaseStorageDownloadTokens` as the key in the metadata dict. Firebase uses that key when creating the access token.